# Cannot debug ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an ionic v1 app. 
It uses following plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.19 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.6-dev "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-transport-security 0.1.2 "App Transport Security"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-facebook-plugin 0.12.0 "Facebook Connect"
```

When I try to run something like `cordova run browser` I have following output

```
Linting www/js/views.js
File www/js/views.js has no errors.
-----------------------------------------
Error: Cannot read property 'variables' of undefined
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it happen the same with other platforms? Like Android or iOS? Since it's a v1 Ionic, shouldn't be ionic run browser? Or, if you've updated to the latest CLI, it's not final yet - so you could try an earlier version - with clean Cordova and plugins installed.

Comment: I don't have iOS but android acts exactly the same way. `ionic run browser` do the same thing

Comment: you can use ionic serve --lab

Comment: Yes, but it's not the same thing. What if I want to debug it on a real device?